# Detach for keeping web browser open in selenium webdriver python not working

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

Okay, so I'm trying to keep the browser open once the script is finished executing. I want to be able to close it manually so the browser doens't close before the user is finished. I'll leave my code below and hopefully someone can help me to see where I'm going wrong. I'm using Chrome as browser. Version 90.0.4430.85

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

# Launch the browser with 4 tabs.


def launchBrowser():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('start-maximized')
# Disables infobar: 'Chrome is being controlled by automation blah blah.' Check: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-launcher/blob/master/docs/chrome-flags-for-tools.md#--enable-automation if anything goes wrong.
    options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
# Ignores certificate and ssl errors.
    options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
    options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors')
# Doesn't work!
    options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
# Reject chrome notifications.
    prefs = {'profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications': 2}
    options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
# This line works for both the maximization of the window and the notifications preference.
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Users\Bernardo\Desktop\Python Projects\Automations\chromedriver.exe')
    
# Main browser, first tab - River.
    driver.get('https://lapaginamillonaria.com/')
    cookies_button = driver.find_element_by_class_name('fc-button.fc-cta-manage-options.fc-secondary-button')
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(cookies_button).click(cookies_button).perform()
    interes_legitimo = driver.find_element_by_class_name('fc-preference-legitimate-interest.purpose') 
    if interes_legitimo.get_attribute('checked') == 'true':
        ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(interes_legitimo).click(interes_legitimo).perform()
        enviar_button = driver.find_element_by_class_name('fc-button.fc-save-continue.fc-primary-button')
        ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(enviar_button).click(enviar_button).perform()
    else:
        print("Couldn't proceed with our task, master Rari.")


# Second tab - La Nación.
    driver.execute_script("window.open('about:blank', 'tab2');")
    driver.switch_to.window("tab2")
    driver.get('https://www.lanacion.com.ar/')


# Third tab - BBC.
    driver.execute_script("window.open('about:blank', 'tab3')")
    driver.switch_to.window("tab3")
    driver.get('https://www.bbc.com/')
    cookies_button = driver.find_element_by_class_name('fc-button.fc-cta-manage-options.fc-secondary-button')
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(cookies_button).click(cookies_button).perform()
    interes_legitimo = driver.find_element_by_class_name('fc-preference-legitimate-interest.purpose') 
    if interes_legitimo.get_attribute('checked') == 'true':
        ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(interes_legitimo).click(interes_legitimo).perform()
        enviar_button = driver.find_element_by_class_name('fc-button.fc-save-continue.fc-primary-button')
        ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(enviar_button).click(enviar_button).perform()
        accept_continue = driver.find_element_by_class_name('continue-button.banner-button')
        ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(accept_continue).click(accept_continue).perform()
    else:
        print("Couldn't proceed with our task.")

    take_me_to_news = driver.find_element_by_class_name('orb-nav-newsdotcom')
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(take_me_to_news).click(take_me_to_news).perform()


launching = launchBrowser()
```